# mysql , codeigniter active record class

Tags: codeigniter

#### table1

```
house_id|house_name|status

  1     |     A    |  1
  2     |     B    |  1
  3     |     C    |  0
  4     |     D    |  1
  5     |     E    |  1
  6     |     F    |  1
```

#### table1

```
house_id| image

   2    | img1.jpg
   2    | img2.jpg
   1    | img3.jpg
   4    | img4.jpg
   1    | img5.jpg
   4    | img6.jpg
   3    | img7.jpg
```

#### I want select all house_id from table1  where status =1 (descending) , select distinct image from table2, for each house_id of table1 .

#### Finally output show bellow :

#### Output

```
house_id|house_name|image

   6    |    F     |NULL
   5    |    E     |NULL
   4    |    D     |img4.jpg
   2    |    B     |img1.jpg  
   1    |    A     |img3.jpg
```

#### please help me code with normal mysql or CI active record class method ..

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you want the code? because this seems pretty easy using left join, and you can easily do that with active record.

Comment: **yes i want code**.@Jonathan Chow

Comment: You do realize that this is a Q&A site, and not a "Do my work for me" site, right?

Comment: thnks  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/732470/kemal-fadillah)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this out....(normal mysql)

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.image FROM table1  t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.house_id=t2.house_id
WHERE t1.status= 1 GROUP BY t1.house_id ORDER BY house_id desc
```

active record...

```
$this->db->select(t1.*,t2.image);
$this->db->from('table1'.' t1');
$this->db->join('table2'.' t2','t1.house_id=t2.house_id','left');
$this->db->where('t1.status',1);
$this->db->group_by("t1.house_id"); 
$this->db->order_by("house_id");
```

Comment: ** sir your answer do not match my given output(given up of the page). there is a missing (6    |    F     |NULL)if I generate your mysql code . . . .- @bipen

Comment: in that case.. then change this line 
    $this->db->group_by("t2.house_id");
to..
    $this->db->group_by("t1.house_id");

Comment: updated the answer.. please check... :)

Comment: yes !! thats works !!!  thakn you !

Comment: :).. ok thn u can accept this as answer....